# Mfp cli WLResourceRequest is not defined error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

i recently converted my mfp studio project to mfp cli cordova project.
when i preview my project everything work fine except "WLResourceRequest is not defined" that log to the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUqPL.png)

i noticed that the web preview works fine, but the mobile browser simulator not working and logs the same error

Comment: And when you test the app in the Android emulator or device, does WLResourceRequest work there?

Comment: didn't tested it yet

Comment: Please try that.  I suspect it is available only on real device testing.

Comment: it freezes on the emulator !  same error as mobile browser simulator error

Comment: Provide a sample project where this is reproducible.

Comment: it is working now, but only freeses when the first page has an adapter call

Comment: So what is your question - freezing, or WLResourceRequest? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: "WLResourceRequest is not defined" what causes that error ?

Comment: Do you have a project that reproduces the error?

Comment: u guys able to solve the issue, If so what is the remedy

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I have a ionic project. This was working till I installed MFP 8.0 beta
Post that I m unable to make any adapter calls.

Comment: did you added an eventListener in your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn`t work in Chrome, but it works on my device. Using MFP 8.0